Who proposed the concept of "electron clouds"?
Who proposed the concept of "electron clouds," which classifies electron orbits in an atom into orbitals (s, p, d, f, etc.) using the Schrödinger equation, and in what year?

The idea of an electron cloud might be old and it precedes Schrödinger's equation. In 1924 Louis de Broglie's thesis, he says that Rutherford and Van den Broek considered the atom to be composed of a nucleus surrounded by an electron cloud.
